# Cannot convert from 'System.IO.FileStream' to 'int' when reading text file into a List

Tags: c#, syntax-error, converters, readfile

All I want to do is have the program read a .txt file, take whatever is in the file, and input it into a list. But it will tell me I can't convert it (no matter if I set the variable as var, string, int, or whatever) I tried using int.TryParse, Convert.ToInt32(), etc. While Convert.ToInt32 shuts it up, when I run the program it crashes.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string listPath = @"K:\listData\listData.txt";
        int listDataSum = 0;
        int listDataMax = 0;
        int listDataMin = 0;
        string userInput = null;

        var numeralListData = System.IO.File.OpenRead(listPath);
        var listData = new List<int>(numeralListData);
        listDataSum = listData.Sum();
        listDataMax = listData.Max();
        listDataMin = listData.Min();

        Console.WriteLine(
            "Please input the data you wish to see, type 'help' for what to type");
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        userInput.ToLower();

        if (userInput == "sum")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The sum of the list is " + listDataSum);
        }
```

EDIT: If the question is a duplicate, please send the link, I tried the search function and all the other questions were way too complicated for someone with as little experience as me to understand.

Comment: Why are you trying to add the file to a list of ints?
Are you trying to read a text file line by line?

Comment: You probably want something like `ReadLines()`.

Comment: Tried using ReadLines, got a similar error.

Comment: @Mike159 the file only contains numbers. The numbers in the file are not line by line, but if needed I can do that.

Comment: you should show sample of the text file because most would assume that it contains integer numbers on separate lines.

Comment: @Slai Yeah I am sorry about that, it was integers on one single line. Mike159's solution works if they are listed line by line, which is what I did, and it worked with Mike's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to read integers from a file, then get their min, max and sum you will want to read each line into a array of strings, then try and convert each string to an int and add it to a list.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string listPath = @"K:\listData\listData.txt";
    int listDataSum = 0;
    int listDataMax = 0;
    int listDataMin = 0;
    string userInput = null;

    var fileReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(listPath);
    List<string> stringsFromFile = new List<string>();
    string lineOfText;
    while ((lineOfText = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        stringsFromFile.Add(lineOfText);
    }
    List<int> intsFromFile = new List<int>();
    foreach(string s in stringsFromFile)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        if(Int32.TryParse(s, out temp))
        {
            intsFromFile.Add(temp);
        }            
    }

    listDataSum = intsFromFile.Sum();
    listDataMax = intsFromFile.Max();
    listDataMin = intsFromFile.Min();

    Console.WriteLine("Please input the data you wish to see, type 'help' for what to type");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    userInput.ToLower();

    if (userInput == "sum")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The sum of the list is " + listDataSum);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using some of your code, I get the error file does not contain a definition for 'StreamReader'

Comment: I fixed what I think was causing the error, try now.

Comment: Awesome, just getting a run time error, but I believe I know how to fix it as the .txt I am using has all the ints on one single line, I just need to seperate them and list it line by line and see if that works, thanks for the help. If it works I will mark it as solved

Comment: Alternatively if your ints are separated by a character you could read all the text and use string.split(); to separate them all into an array.

Comment: Yep, just needed to list it line by line, thank you so much @Mike159 for the help!

Comment: You should close the stream reader after using it. Or use the using statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming each number is on a different line in your text file**

- First read all the lines
- Convert all the lines to a new list or array with `TryParse` from `string` to `int`
- Operate directly with a method and parameter to do calculations (so you can reuse it). Now you are doing calculations with `Max();` etc. that you maybe not going to use if the user doesn't asks it.

Example: *(bit different approach then yours, hope you learn from it)*

```
static void Main(string[] args)    
{
    string listPath = @"K:\listData\listData.txt";

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(listPath).ToList();

    var number = 0;
    var numbers = lines.Where(line => int.TryParse(line, out number)).Select(n => number).ToList();         

    Console.WriteLine("Please input the data you wish to see, type 'help' for what to type");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

    if (userInput == "sum")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The sum of the list is " + ListDataSum(numbers));
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static int ListDataSum(List<int> list)
{
    return list.Sum();
}
```